# Background color not 100% when mobile keyboard is open

Tags: android, html, css

I am developing a web messaging app using HTML and CSS. I encounter a bug when the mobile keyboard is open and I scroll, the background color is not 100% of the viewport's height. What is causing this? And how do I fix this?

| Step 1 | Step 2 | Step 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [image: Screenshot of the site] | [image] | [image] |

Comment: Can you please let me know about the height properties that you have set?

Comment: i have set the body using 100vw and 100vh and background-color: #0d0d0dcc; the problem is when the keyboard is open in mobile devices and when content is overflowing and i scroll the background-color is not occupying all the spaces

Comment: Try using adding this property to the body. 
background-attachment: fixed;

Comment: still not works and it is background color not background-image?

Comment: Yes, We can add a new div inside the body and can set CSS to that. For e.g. 
<div style="position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100vw; height: 100vh; background-color: #0d0d0dcc; z-index: -1;"></div>

Comment: Thankyou so much! This fixed the problem maybe the position fixed.

Comment: Yes. By setting the position property to fixed, the background layer will remain in place and cover the entire viewport, even when scrolling with the mobile keyboard open. You're welcome. Have a good day !!